# Angular Universal server API requesting

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I just migrated my application to Angular 6 + Universal. It`s great but I have 2 issues to fix. Please help me for both ones:

1- How can I run the Angular Universal app in --watch mode for developing time?
Before that I opened **2 terminal**. In one of them I wrote command: `nodemon server.js` and in another on : `ng build --watch`. In this situation I was developing my application fast by real-time editing.

But now after each edit I use command `npm run build:ssr`. I takes lots of time. There should be another way for increase developing time in Angular Universal?!

2- The other issue is before I migrate to Angular Universal, I was using express to for server side same as now. I have called an API handler file like this:

```
const api = require('./routes/api');
app.use('/api', api);
```

How can I do this in new angular universal package like before in `server.ts` file?

Comment: 1 . There is no watch mode still available with angular universal
2. you can import by import api from './routes/api and use the app.use('/api',api);

Answer (score 1):

For Angular7 run `npm run ssr:watch`

[package.json](https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter/blob/master/package.json)

```
    "ssr:watch": "run-p ssr:universal:build:*",
    "ssr:universal:build:browser": "ng run universal-demo:build --watch",
    "ssr:universal:build:server": "node ./node_modules/npm-delay 12000 && ng run universal-demo:server --watch",
    "ssr:universal:build:webpack": "node ./node_modules/npm-delay 20000 && webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch",
    "ssr:universal:build:nodemon": "node ./node_modules/npm-delay 25000 && nodemon --inspect server.js",
```